# System Verilog - case with or

Tags: case, verilog, system-verilog

How can I create case with or?

Something like:

```
string str;

case (str)
   "abc" || "dfg": begin
       //some code
   end
   "yfg": begin
       //some code
   end
   default: //some code
endcase
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a `case` with OR using a comma like this:

```
string str;

case (str)
   "abc" , "dfg": begin  
       //some code
   end
   "yfg": begin
       //some code
   end
   default: //some code
endcase
```

What you're doing is subtly different to `||`. You are presenting a list of alternatives to the `case` statement instead of ORing several expressions together to give one alternative to the `case` statement.